# How to skip specific line preg_replace - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I made a small function that is removing extra whitespace from strings

```
/* remove white space */
function wspace($string){

    $string = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

it works nice but the issue I have is following; 
if I am using this function on js strings wich is intended , the lines that have commments like

```
// will brake js output,
```

Example

```
      $js_string .="
        window.addEvent('load', function(){
            new Drop({
                container:'container',
                offset: ".$offset.", // top menu offset
                width:200
            });
        });
      ";

echo wspace( $js_string );
```

this will output

```
window.addEvent('load', function(){ new Drop({ container:'container',offset: ".$offset.", // top menu offset width:200 }); });";
```

which is commenting out everything after `//`

how would I go about skipping or replacing those lines with `/*` or anything that would not mess-up the rest of the code?

I know that replacing `//` with `/*` comment `*/`  is what should be done, but I am making update on my old script that is widely used and I don't know if users have `//` or /`*` comment `*/` . So in order to not break someone's code I need to be certain before I release this.

I would like to do something like

```
if($string contains // ) skip to next line
```

or anything that you think it would work to make this function more secure.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) can have array as pattern and replace.

```
function wspace($string){
    $string = preg_replace( array('/[^:]\/\/.*$/m','/\/\*.*\*\//U', '/\s+/'), array('','',' '), $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Edit:

If you also want to remove the /* ... */ comment from the script, You can use this

```
function wspace($string){
    echo $string;
    $string = preg_replace( array('/[^:]\/\/.*$/m','/\/\*.*\*\//U', '/\s+/'), array('','',' '), $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Note: I have not tested these on real javascript functions.
Edit: made it `://url...` safe.

Comment: I am testing it but something is still messing it up . ah , found the issue , there is variable that contains http://sitelink.com , so I get var sp = 'http: var tp ='

Comment: It actualy works for the question asked so your are right , how would I go about skipping the http://   ?

Comment: ok , and extra space helped found the comments like //space comment and not //comment and it leaves the var with http://  alone

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
# this first part skips content between quotes
(["']) (?>[^'"\\]+|\\.|(?!\1)["'])* \1 (*SKIP)(*FAIL)
|
# this part matches comments and capture the content in group 2
//(\N*)
|
# this part matches whitespace characters
\s+
~xs
EOD;
```

And then use it with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
     return ($m[2]) ? '/* ' . trim($m[2]) . ' */' : ' ';
}, $data);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: That's some excellent regex Casimir (as always). I especially like the `(?!\1)["'])* \1` to simulate character class negation. +1.

Comment: @AmalMurali: Thanks and for the edit too! However this pattern can be simplified. I will correct that.